# Water pressure in upstairs sink lost after turning off main line to fix shower

Tags: bathroom, water, sink, water-pressure

So yesterday I had to replace the handle on the shower-- and because I couldn't access the valve to the shower, I had to shut off the main valve to the entire house.  I switched out the handle and everything is great.  Except now the same bathroom with said shower has a sink that no longer has any water pressure.  I.e, it just trickles water, both from the hot and cold valves (If I shut off the cold valve, it will trickle if I move it to hot, and it will turn off when I switch it to cold-- and vice versa with hot)

Every other sink, bathtub, shower, everything has the appropriate water pressure.

I'm worried that I broke something, but I have no idea.  I don't see leaks anywhere, nor do I hear any leaks.  House is at 64 so I don't think anything froze?  Anybody have any ideas what could've happened?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you shut off your main (or any valve really but the main is the big one) and turn it back on you can cause debris or sediment that was trapped somewhere in your plumbing to dislodge.

It seems to me that some debris might have gotten trapped in that faucet's aerator. Remove it and see if the pressure seems fine.

If the pressure seems fine with the aerator removed, clean the aerator.

If there is still low pressure try to close and open the shutoff valve for that faucet (with the aerator still removed) to try to dislodge anything that might have gotten stuck in that valve but chances are it's the aerator.

Comment: Thanks; this helped me remove a piece of debris from my shower head when I had replaced a faucet handle stem.