# Loss of water pressure after replacing shower head

Tags: plumbing, water, shower, water-pressure

I recently installed a new shower head (30 bucks from amazon) and afterwards started to hear a high pitch sound when I turn the water on. It started off as on and off then one day the sound got really loud and all of a sudden the water pressure dropped to about half of the force.

It's since been like that for a week now. I even switched it back to the old shower head and it's still the same half pressure.

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening? is this something I can fix myself or need a plumber?

Comment: post a picture to warn us not to buy it

Comment: When you were replacing the shower head, which valve did you use ?

Comment: Where is the noise coming from - the shower head? inside the wall? at the bathtub spout if you have a combo shower/bath?  I suspect something broke off and is partially blocking the water flow. An older rubber gasket at the hot/cold water valves could disintegrate and send a piece downstream partially blocking flow. If you have a "diverter valve" directing water to either the shower head or the tub spout, the moving part inside can wear and cause issues.  If you closed a shut off valve upstream while you were working, a rubber gasket in that could have broken and sent pieces downstream.

Comment: This might be related: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/60762/water-pressure-in-upstairs-sink-lost-after-turning-off-main-line-to-fix-shower

Comment: This might be related: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/186150/reduced-hot-water-pressure-after-closing-and-reopening-water-supply-in-one-upsta

Comment: Replacing a shower head is almost as simple as changing a light bulb.  Imagine you had another part that failed at the same time. Probably the valves that control the shower(if that is the only problem area).  Will to use the shut off valves, not the taps, to work on them.

Comment: What's the flow like with NO shower head attached? That may even flush out the blockage, which could well be bits of old washer. And, if you turned off water at the mains, are all other taps o.k? (inc. toilets).

Answer (score 0):

My bets are on the Valve you used to shut down the water to replace the shower head.

It is not fully open now creating the problems.

The shower head has probably pressure regulator build in.

Check the valve handle if it tight.

Comment: Replacing a shower head is probably about the only plumbing that is easy to do, even if you are showering at the time.  This problem probably happen at the same time, but another place/valve.